# Qstat error in Eqw

Tags: linux

can any one help to understand how to solve that problem?

```
 365227 0.50500 towhee     jmaia        Eqw   07/19/2014 19:22:55
```

when I do:

```
  qstat -j 365228 | grep error
```

that appears:

```
error reason    1:          07/19/2014 18:23:25 [1007:1354]: execvp(/usr/sge/default/spool/node25/job_scripts/365228, "/usr/sge/
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try it with `| grep -A 10 error`.

Comment: lol that appears: error reason    1:          07/19/2014 19:50:41 [1007:6526]: execvp(/usr/sge/default/spool/node16/job_scripts/365230, "/usr/sge/
scheduling info:            (Collecting of scheduler job information is turned off)

Comment: can any one help me? :s

Comment: Why do you believe this is a problem?  What is `Eqw` -- something to do with video games, right?  Is it working properly, or not? You haven't provided much information.

Comment: this is the only information that i have.. i try to run a simulation program, and this problem only ocurs in a specific directory.. lol

Comment: *Why do you believe this is a problem?*  Is there something you are doing that does not work?  If so describe it (by editing the question, not with comments).

Comment: @goldilocks I don't think it is a nice state in a PBS queueing system, but it might be better for the OP to consult the system administrator.